# How can I know which country code should be used for translation file?

Tags: magento2, localisation, translate

I want to translate store to Serbian language and in official Serbian translation there are 2 types Alphabet and Cirilic letters:

- sr_SP.csv
- sr_CS.csv

But there is only one Serbian in localisation options on admin panel.

P.S.
To further investigate this can I add made up language and make it appear in localisation options as an option?

Answer (score 0):

So as no one answered I researched more and found that language codes are defined in:

```
magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Locale/Config.php
```

So if you also have trouble translating, check [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Locale/Config.php) file to find out your country code. 
To answer my other question yes we can add made up language like explained in [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198111/how-to-customize-locale-country-code?rq=1).  But its kinda tempering with core, not a good practice.